# TableViewCell - DetailtextLabel to call WebViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, rss

I'm working on RSS app, and in my last view (tableView), i would like to use the cell.detailTextlabel to call the WebViewController and open the related article in Safari.

Actually I don't know if this is the best way, but i need to have this "Read More" to open the whole article.

In the end of my third section (attached image), i inserted the "Read More" - detailTextLabel.text = @"Read More" - but i don't know how to link to the WebViewController and to pass the correct URL.

Searching on the net, i found this example to open in Safari:

```
**WebViewController.h** 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)postURL title:(NSString *)postTitle;

@end


**WebViewController.m**

    @implementation WebViewController
    @synthesize url = _url, webView = _webView;

 - (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)postURL title:(NSString *)postTitle
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _url = postURL;
        self.title = postTitle;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.url = [self.url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet       whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL]];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}

 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: In the simplest way, You may try putting a custom button with Read More title in cell's `contentView` and call the WebViewController on that event.

Comment: The way you mentioned, to put the button in the right place, i can use the CGRectMake? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I edited the answer,check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom `UIButton` instance to the tableview cell and tag it with indexPath.row or indexPath.section according to your structure. On the button action, get the sender's tag and get the exact URL out of your dataSource Array and call WenViewController with that URL.
You can add the button in cell's contentView with desired frame. For eg

```
CGRect cellFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
UIButton *readMore = [[UIButton alloc] 
                     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x+20, cellFrame.origin.y+cellFrame.size.height - yourButtonHeight -10, yourButtonWidth, yourButtonHeight)];
[readMore addTarget:self action:@selector(openWebView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[readMore setTitle:@"Read More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[readMore setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:readMore];
// Release readMore button if not using ARC
```

And then make the method

```
-(void)openWebView:(UIButton*)sender{
      int tag = sender.tag;
      // Get URL from array using tag as index
}
```

Comment: Instead of pass indexPath.row to the "setTag", i can pass one property of another class, which grab the address passed in another tableView by didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Thanks

Comment: @Edward Yeah or you can create a subclass of `UIButton` to hold the url for you as a property and access it by getting that property. You can accept this as answer if this helped you.